# How do I write this regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

Basically, for this regex

```
{(\(\(("\w{1,}",{0,1}){2}\),\(("[^:=;@"\)\(\{\}\[\]]{1,}",{0,1}){2}"[LR]{1}"\)\),{0,1}){1,}}
```

Which I've tested on Regexpal for this input:

{(("st0","sy0"),("st1","sy3","L")),(("st0","sy0"),("st1","^","L"))}

I now need in Java. I can't seem to figure out how to convert it. Can somebody show me how to?

Comment: What are you trying to match? sample input? sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the special chars - specifically the backslashes and the quote marks.

Comment: Can you explain specifically? I've tried escaping the ones I thought it was but don't seem to be getting the right ones? Also any advice on how to learn regex would be great seeing as I'm clueless for it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression could work on Java, the only thing that you have to do, is escape the backslash .